# Does size_t have the same size and alignment as ptrdiff_t?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, size-t, ptrdiff-t

On my platform (and on most of them I think) `std::size_t` and `std::ptrdiff_t`  have the same size and the same alignment. Is there any platform where that is not true? In short: is it required by the standard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In short: is it required by the standard?

No.  The only requirement is from [[support.types.layout]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/support.types#layout-2) and it is:

> The type ptrdiff_­t is an implementation-defined signed integer type that can hold the difference of two subscripts in an array object, as described in [expr.add].

There is [paragraph 4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/support.types#layout-4)

> [ Note: It is recommended that implementations choose types for ptrdiff_­t and size_­t whose integer conversion ranks are no greater than that of signed long int unless a larger size is necessary to contain all the possible values. — end note ]

but notes are non-normative and it is only a recommendation, not a requirement.

---

`std::size_t` is defined as

> The type size_­t is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object ([expr.sizeof]).

in [paragraph 3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/support.types#layout-3) and it also has no requirement that they be the same.

Comment: You might also want to note the requirement for `size_t`, which is immediately after the requirement you have linked for `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: @Peter Added into the answer

Comment: On what platform is `ptrdiff_t` not a signed version of `size_t`?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin AFAIK, none.  That said, there is no guarantee that will hold for all systems.

Comment: What about 16-bit systems (without the huge code model)?  In that case, `size_t` would naturally be 16 bits, but you'd expect `ptrdiff_t` to be larger so that you can have `char` arrays of size between 32K and 64K.  Indeed there's a note at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t that C++11 requires `ptrdiff_t` to be at least 17 bits wide.

Answer (score 3):

It is not required by the standard.

Note that the current crop of Intel processors have 48 bit pointers under the hood.

So personally I don't see it too far-fetched to conceive a 64 bit `unsigned` for `std::size_t` and a 49 bit signed type for a `std::ptrdiff_t`. Although such a scheme would be a headache to implement.

More interestingly once chipsets evolve to have 64 bit pointers (we are some way off that being necessary), presumably `std::ptrdiff_t` will have to be at least 65 bits! Personally therefore I keep in mind that one day `sizeof(std::ptrdiff_t)` may be larger than `sizeof(std::size_t)`.

Comment: Under the hood the pointers are still 64 bits. x86_64 requires the top 16 bits to be a copy of bit 47. ARM64 can ignore the top byte in a 64-bit pointer which one can use for tags.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: I was going to wade in with a contradiction, but I notice that, like me, you're a childhood Z80 programmer! I wrote some of the "sprite" code that made it into some of the commercial games: Sorcery for one. Note the hideous use of XOR!

Comment: Did you intend to say that Z80 was an 8-bit processor with 16-bit addresses? `xor` was the basis of many copy-protection/code-encryption back in those days, especially with undocumented R register, which you could not just step through in the debugger to decrypt the code. I may have played Sorcery back then! Truly high performance code used `push` to draw on the screen, because it was the fastest way to store a word and move to the previous write position.

Answer (score 0):

> On my platform ... `std::size_t` and `std::ptrdiff_t` have the same size

How is this compliant?

C has (which I believe C++ inherits - if not let me know to delete) as UB in § J.2:

> The result of subtracting two pointers is not representable in an object of type `ptrdiff_t` (6.5.6)."

This allows the type of `ptrdiff_t` to be the signed counterpart of the unsigned `size_t`.
When paired as such with no padding,

```
char a[PTRDIFF_MAX + (size_t)1];         // OK with enough memory in the location needed
size_t size_a = sizeof a;                // OK             
size_t diff0 = &a[sizeof a - 1] - &a[0]; // OK
ptrdiff_t diff1 = &a[sizeof a] - &a[0];  // UB
ptrdiff_t diff2 = %a[0] - &a[sizeof a];  // UB
```

Moral of the story: troubles with pointer subtraction (result type: `ptrdiff_t`) *may* begin when the array *element count* exceeds `PTRDIFF_MAX`.